# Add padding to div, if (vertical) scrollbar is visible in another div

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, event-handling, scrollbar

Folks, I have the following HTML with Bootstrap classes.

```
<div class="header">some stuff aligned to main</div>
<div class="main overflow-y-auto">some tabular stuff
  <div class="record">data goes here</div>
  <div class="record">data goes here</div>
  <div class="record">data goes here</div>
</div>
```

How can I add some padding to the .header div (e.g. addClass("pr-3"), if and only if the .main div has the vertical scrollbar visible (due to the amount of content that's in there.

I understand, I can determine, whether the scroll is visible on an element by comparing `element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight`. I guess my question is, how do I link in an event handler that checks, when the scroll becomes visible, and when it disappears again. Obviously, the .main div isnt static or even a static  field, but dynamically made up of a number of s (".record"). Those are added by some a `$(.main).append($record.clone());` statement and populated by mySQL data.

Why do I want to do that? The .header contains the labels for the fields in the .main div. When there is more data than space, the scrollbar is added automatically, reformatting the field-width as appropriate. The result is that that the labels in the .header div arent fully aligned anymore with the fields below.

Any thoughts?

Comment: How do you create/insert/show this content ?

Comment: Lapskaus, I updated the post. Basically the records are added by appending a record template, which is then populated by mySQL data retrieved via php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to wrap your `.header` and `.main` class into another element. Then just check for each of these wrappers, if their corrosponding `main` element has a scrollbar - like you suggested with `scrollHeight > height()` - and if so, add your class to the wrappers `header` element:

```js
$('.some-wrapper-class').each(function() {
 let $header = $(this).find('.header');
  let $content = $(this).find('.main');
  console.log($content[0].scrollHeight > $content.height()) ;
  if($content[0].scrollHeight > $content.height()) {
    $header.addClass('text-danger');
  }
});
```

```css
.header {
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.header-padded {
  color: red;
}

.main {
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="some-wrapper-class">
  <div class="header">Header with scrollbar</div>
  <div class="main overflow-auto">
    some tabular stuff
    <div class="record">data goes here</div>
    <div class="record">data goes here</div>
    <div class="record">data goes here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="some-wrapper-class">
  <div class="header">Header without scrollbar</div>
  <div class="main overflow-auto">
    some tabular stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to fully type out a working code - much appreciated. The core of the code works and does what it should, when I attach it to the event a) when new data is generated and b) the window is resized.  I'm still it a bit puzzled by what the wrapper actually does and where you suggest the script snippet goes? I have tried to put in in the $(document).ready callback ... but then it's not triggered by new data ...

Comment: The wrapper serves 2 purposes, **#1** It reflects the connection between the header and the main element in your code and makes it easy to understand that they belong together. **#2** without it, it would be alot harder to select the right header for the right main element. 
If you dynamically add elements, you can wrap the whole js code in a function and run that when you attach new elements (in addition to runing it on `document.ready`) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f7Lbk0jd/)